# Insert data to Excel table using OLEDb

Tags: c#, oledbcommand

My code looks like

```
    using System.Data.OleDb;


    namespace ConsoleApplication21
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                string constr2 = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\productivity\temp.xlsx;Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=no'";

            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(constr2);
            conn.Open();

            OleDbCommand INSERTcommand = new OleDbCommand();
            INSERTcommand.Connection = conn;
            INSERTcommand.CommandText = "create table [table3] (id INT, name VARCHAR, datecol DATE);";
            INSERTcommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            OleDbCommand INSERTDATA = new OleDbCommand();
            INSERTDATA.Connection = conn;
            INSERTDATA.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [table3] (id,name,datecol) values (1,'aaaa','25-01-2012');";
            INSERTDATA.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
    }
}
```

After executing the above code an exception shows:

> The INSERT INTO statement contains the following unknown field name:
>   'id'. Make sure you have typed the name correctly, and try the
>   operation again.

Comment: can you omit id column and check if the rest works?

Comment: also check using brackets like you did with tablename. `INSERT INTO [table3] ([id], [name ], ...) VALUES ... `

Comment: I omit id column and still the same problem, also I tried ([id],[name],...) also not working

Comment: and `"create table [table3] (id INT, .....` works errorless?

Comment: yes "create table [table3] .... work errorless

Comment: just wanted to repro the error, but ACE OLEDB is missing. how did you install(?) it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you omit the column specifications while inserting, it works fine:

`INSERTDATA.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [table3]  values (1,'aaaa','25-01-2012');";`

Comment: did you ever checked this answer? @Saher